# Publishing to Facebook user feed from NodeJs

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

If I do the publishing with a curl command everything works correctly:

```
curl \
    -F 'access_token=...' \
    -F 'message=hello' \
    https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed
```

And the response is:

```
{"id":"100001692713927_542460169153735"}
```

But doing the same from NodeJs making the POST using the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module:

```
var formData = {
    access_token: '...',
    message: 'hello5'
};

request.post('https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed', formData, function (error, response, body) { … });
```

I get the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) This API call requires a valid app_id.", 
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200
    }
}
```

I used both `me` and the user ID in the URL and the behavior is the same.

What can be wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The problem in the above code is the wrong format of the `request.post` data parameter. t should be:

```
var formData = {
    form: {
        access_token: "...",
        message: "hello"
    }
};
```

This was the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to use Facebook SDK for Node.js, [this](https://github.com/DracoBlue/node-facebook-client) might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I have also just found the problem and posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think facebook POST request expects app_id -which is something you will get when you create an application at facebook over here - https://developers.facebook.com/apps .

That app_id when provided shall get you through.